# Regex to convert URL to Links

Tags: javascript, regex

I 'borrowed' a regex from this website : http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls that is almost complete but i want to match exemple.com
I know that stackoverflow is not doyourhomework.com but I passed a long time thinking without results. Here is a fiddle to test : http://jsfiddle.net/BGnMm/25/ and you can see at the end that exemple.com is not a link.

```
var reg=/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/*)|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi;
var allurl="http:foo.com/blah_blah http://foo.com/blah_blah/ (Something like http://foo.com/blah_blah) http://foo.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia) http://foo.com/more_(than)_one_(parens) (Something like http://foo.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)) http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)#cite-1 http://foo.com/blah_(wikipedia)_blah#cite-1 http://foo.com/unicode_(✪)_in_parens http://foo.com/(something)?after=parens http://foo.com/blah_blah. http://foo.com/blah_blah/. <http://foo.com/blah_blah> <http://foo.com/blah_blah/> http://foo.com/blah_blah, http://www.extinguishedscholar.com/wpglob/?p=364. http://✪df.ws/1234 rdar://1234 rdar:/1234 x-yojimbo-item://6303E4C1-6A6E-45A6-AB9D-3A908F59AE0E message://%3c330e7f840905021726r6a4ba78dkf1fd71420c1bf6ff@mail.gmail.com%3e http://➡.ws/䨹 www.c.ws/䨹 <tag>http://example.com</tag> Just a www.example.com link. http://example.com/something?with,commas,in,url, but not at end What about <mailto:gruber@daringfireball.net?subject=TEST> (including brokets). mailto:name@example.com bit.ly/foo “is.gd/foo/” WWW.EXAMPLE.COM http://www.asianewsphoto.com/(S(neugxif4twuizg551ywh3f55))/Web_ENG/View_DetailPhoto.aspx?PicId=752 http://www.asianewsphoto.com/(S(neugxif4twuizg551ywh3f55)) http://lcweb2.loc.gov/cgi-bin/query/h?pp/horyd:@field(NUMBER+@band(thc+5a46634)) 6:00p filename.txt http://example.com/quotes-are-“part” ✪df.ws/1234 example.com example.com/";
document.write(allurl.replace(reg,"<a href='$1' >$1</a><br />"));
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question for future reference. I have updated it, but links should be secondary (what if this link was removed)...Also, what are you trying to do?

Comment: If this is homework, you should add the "homework" tag.

Comment: i just said it's not homework

Comment: I am trying to change the regex so exemple.com is matched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an alternation operator (`|`) after the `{2,4}\/`, i.e.

```
    var reg=/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/*)|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/|)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi;
```

There's something you should understand about this.  The first non-captured group, `(?: … )`, looks for "indicators" of URLs.  One indicator, for example, is the `www` (followed by up to 3 digits of numbers).  You however are asking for a way to identify URLs *without any indicator at all*.  So, what we've done above is we've added a clause, "*or an empty match*," as a "valid" indicator.  **The consequence of this is that your regular expression is less selective now: all sorts of strings, not only <kbd>example.com</kbd> but also <kbd>filename.txt</kbd>, <kbd>3.141593</kbd>, and <kbd>omg...really</kbd> are identified as URLs!**  Your only other (readily available) option is to be more selective about suffixes, e.g. require specific suffixes (`com|org|net`), but then this takes away from the generality of the original regex, which doesn't specify any suffixes at all.

In other words, you are probably faced with a limitation of logic, not a limitation of regex-writing skills or the regex language itself.

Comment: +1. Your examples show why such a thing shouldn't be added, IMO example.com shouldn't be linked as an URL. If OP wants to link it as url, just add the `http://` protocol as in `http://example.com`. If this automatic URL-identifying were to be implemented in a forum board for example, the users' posts would have many unintentional (and possibly broken) links. Defining suffixes as you suggested could be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if

```
var reg=/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/*)|(?:www\d{0,3}[.])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/{0,1})(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))*(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi;
```

suits your needs. www(anyNumber) has just been put to appear one or zero times. Sorry for the first answer, did not notice the texts.