# Regular Expression to match URLs / web addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JS function which is passed a string that a RegEx is run against, and returns any matches:

```
searchText= // some string which may or may not contain URLs
Rxp= new RegExp("([a-zA-Z\d]+://)?(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(/.*)?/ig")
return searchText.match(Rxp);
```

The RegExp should return matches for any of the following (and similar derivations):

- google.com
- www.google.com
- http://www.google.com
- http://google.com
- google.com?querystring=value
- www.google.com?querystring=value
- http://www.google.com?querystring=value
- http://google.com?querystring=value

However, no such luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but I suggest you to see this website : http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: If you want to specify a regex by things it should match, it'd help to say what patterns it shouldn't match.

Comment: I'd seen the Daring Fireball one, but it doesnt match e.g. 'google.com'

Comment: @ErgoSummary Yes because it shouldn't. For exemple, if you write "hi all.how are you?" it will be converted to "hi http://all.how are you?" See a full explanation here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10505843/1365010 (Note that stackoverflow doesn't match google.com too)

Comment: @user1365010, I know the pitfalls, however it needs to match in this incidence (various other cross checks take place), the regex is a loose first stage identifier of 'url like strings'

Comment: @ErgoSummary if you really need to match it, see the regex in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10505843/1365010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a string, `\` has to be escaped: `\\`.

First, the string is interpreted. `\w` turns in `w`, because it has no significant meaning.
*Then*, the parsed string is turned in a RegEx. But `\` is lost during the string parsing, so your RegEx breaks.

Instead of using the `RegExp` constructor, use RegEx literals:

```
Rxp = /([a-zA-Z\d]+:\/\/)?(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(\/.*)?/ig;
// Note: I recommend to use a different variable name. Variables starting with a
//  capital usually indicate a constructor, by convention.
```

If you're not 100% sure that the input is a string, it's better to use the [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method, which coerces the argument to a string:

```
return Rxp.exec(searchText);
```

Here's a pattern which includes the query string and URL fragment:

```
/([a-zA-Z\d]+:\/\/)?(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(\/[^?#\s]*‌)?(\?[^#\s]*)?(#\S*)?/ig
```

Comment: Also, the `/ig` at the end is not going to work as expected. Better use a regex literal instead.

Comment: +1 for the literal. However, now you have to escape the slashes inside the regex.

Comment: Many thanks, looks like a huge improvement- for matches that end with '?querystring=value' (i.e. a URL querystring) that part is omitted from the returned value?

Comment: @ErgoSummary Do you want to include the query string? Use something along the lines of `(\?[^#\s]+)?` (assuming that your URLs end where a space starts).

Comment: If present the query string should be returned, the URLs will end either with a space, or at the end of the string itself. How would I incorporate the above into the overall string? Apologies for my lack of RegExp know-how

Comment: @Rob W, Thanks- however it returns an error (eg on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html)?

Comment: @ErgoSummary There is an invisible character in the pattern. `/([a-zA-Z\d]+:\/\/)?(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(\/[^?#\s]*)?(\?[^#\s]*)?(#\S*)?/ig.exec('http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html')` works fine. EDIT: Again. I'll add the pattern to my answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's no real need to create your pattern via the RegExp constructor since it doesn't contain anything dynamic. You can just use the literal `/pattern/` instead.

If you do use the constructor, though, you have to remember your pattern is declared as a string, not a literal REGEXP, so you'll need to double-escape special characters, e.g. `\\d`, not `\d`. Also, there were several forward slashes you weren't escaping at all.

With the constructor, modifiers (g, i) are passed as a second argument, not appended to the pattern.

So to literally change what you have, it would be:

```
Rxp= new RegExp("([a-zA-Z\\d]+:\\/\\/)?(\\w+:\\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\\d.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\\d+)?(\\/.*)?", "ig")
```

But better would be:

```
Rxp = /([a-zA-Z\d]+:\/\/)?(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:\d+)?(\/.*)?/gi;
```

Comment: In the `RegExp` constructor, there is no need to escape the slashes. Only in the regex literal.

Comment: Ah I'd never realised that, thanks. Guess it didn't harm to do it, just didn't have any effect.